# How to determine datatype of SQL query expression

Tags: sql, db2

I need to pass output of query to my Datastage Job, which will process it further. Problem is that I used type conversion and calculation in my SQL query, and DataStage needs to know the exact datatype of the input columns.

Simpler way is to guess the column type, for Ex: CAST it to INT 
But sometimes its INT64 and then I have to change it, so I'm looking for something reliable which will save me time.

More like Metadata of Resultset.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how you execute your query.

In the DB2 command line processor you can use the [command `DESCRIBE SELECT <the rest of your query>`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002019.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0&lang=en) to print the list of result set columns along with their data types.

In a batch script you can parse the output of `DESCRIBE`.

In a CLI or embedded SQL application you can use the corresponding [`DESCRIBE OUTPUT` statement](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0052686.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-12-7-127&lang=en) to retrieve the result set metadata into the SQLDA structure.

This assumes DB2 for LUW, but the `DESCRIBE` statement is supported by DB2 for z/OS and IBM i (AS/400) as well.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks buddy.